Find absolute difference value between elements using just NumPy array operations
a = np.array([101,105,90,102,90,10,50])
b = np.array([99,110,85,110,85,90,60])

expected result = np.array([2,5,5,8,5,20,10])

How can I find minimum absolute difference value between elements using just numpy operations; with modulus of 100 if two values are across 100.

What have you tried?  np.abs(a-b) for a start? x%100 does modulus.

@123 np.minium is what I needed. It worked.

The answer you accepted says the difference between 10 and 90 is 20, but the difference between 90 and 10 is 80. Is this really what you want?

@user2357112 imagine a clock with 100 minutes, the minimal absolute difference between 90 and 10 is indeed 20 (90->100 + 0->10).

@mozway: Yeah, I know, but the accepted answer at the time said it was 80, so I was trying to figure out if the questioner really wanted that answer's behavior.

The answer by Derek Roberts with numpy.minimum is almost correct. However, since the input values can be greater than 100, they should first be rescaled to 0-100 with %100 (mod). I'm adding an extra pair of values to demonstrate this:
a = np.array([101,105,90,102,90,10,50,1001])
b = np.array([99,110,85,110,85,90,60,2])

x = abs(a%100-b%100)
np.minimum(x, 100-x)

Generic computation:
M = 100
x = abs(a%M-b%M)
np.minimum(x, M-x)

Output:
array([ 2,  5,  5,  8,  5, 20, 10,  1])


damn, you were awarded the points sad much... you used my reputation haha @mozway nice

@Derek sorry about that. However, to be fair, @123 had posted the minimum approach first (their answer considered the modulo incorrectly and yours not at all).

I just realized what you were saying just now,  that wow anyways... no worries

This is a classic example of what Modulus Arithmetic is used for
Let us consider an example
Morris provides everything you need to know about modulus here
My source: maths
"Definition Let m > 0 be a positive integer called the modulus. We say that two integers a and b are
congruent modulo m if b − a is divisible by m. In other words,
a ≡ b(modm) ⇐⇒ a − b = m · k for some integers
"
Let us take 10 and 90 for example:
In other words, moving directly from 10 to 90 gives a difference of 80, but if you consider the wrap-around (going backward from 10 to 0 and then forward from 100 to 90), you get a smaller difference of 20.
I have provide a code which helps
For example:
import numpy as np

a = np.array([101, 105, 90, 102, 90, 10, 50])
b = np.array([99, 110, 85, 110, 85, 90, 60])

# Start by computing absolute difference
absolute_of_two_nos = np.abs(a % 100 - b % 100)

# Then consider the difference- wrap-around using modulus of 100
diff_mod_using_100 = 100 - np.abs(a % 100 - b % 100)

# Take the minimum of the direct diff and the modulus diff
result = np.minimum(absolute_of_two_nos, diff_mod_using_100)

print(result)


One way to do this is to use np.minimum() with abs():
import numpy as np

a = np.array([101, 105, 90, 102, 90, 10, 50])
b = np.array([99, 110, 85, 110, 85, 90, 60])

print(np.minimum(abs(a - b)%100, abs((b - a) % 100)))



This gives different absolute differences between 10 and 90 and between 90 and 10, which is unlikely to be the desired behavior.

Second term has to be np.abs(b-a)

After the edit, this still gives different absolute differences between 10 and 90 and between 90 and 10. It also doesn't give the expected output for the given test case.

I guess OP mistook the second to the last element by writing 20 instead of 80. above method seems right.

I deleted my answer as your answer seems more right. I upvoted yours too as I saw someone downvoted it without any reason to comment on. this is really disturbing in SO. there should be a law that no one should downvote without a comment so we know who downvoted for no reason.

@hamflow not the downvoter, but this answer is actually incorrect. If you try with a = 2 ; b = 1001 the output will incorrectly be 99 (it should be 1).

Thank you @mozway. you are right. this answer can be edited as: print(np.minimum(abs(a - b)%100, abs((b - a) % 100)))   and then it works. something similar to your answer. however,I still believe downvoting without a comment is really wrong. Thank you again.

@hamflow you again haha, You are on a crusade aint you? I remember you.

@derek-roberts thank you. I lost most of the wars I was in so probably not a crusaide

import numpy as np

a = np.array([101, 105, 90, 102, 90, 10, 50])
b = np.array([99, 110, 85, 110, 85, 90, 60])



def min_abs_diff_with_modulus(a, b):

    # Calculate the absolute differences
    diffs = np.abs(a - b)

    # Apply the modulus of 100 if the difference is greater than 50
    diffs[diffs > 50] = 100 - diffs[diffs > 50]

    return diffs


result = min_abs_diff_with_modulus(a, b)
print(result)
'''
[ 2  5  5  8  5 20 10]
'''

Method 2 :
import numpy as np

a = np.array([101, 105, 90, 102, 90, 10, 50])
b = np.array([99, 110, 85, 110, 85, 90, 60])

diffs = np.abs(a -b)

mod_diffs = np.minimum(diffs, 100 - diffs)

print(mod_diffs)#[ 2  5  5  8  5 20 10]

